# filter rows in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a winform c# SQL app that retrieves data from a table stores it in a datatable and then passes it on to a report viewer.

the data table stores a maximum of 110+ columns. Some of those particular columns have "N/A" values, which i don't want to display to the user.

i tried using the dataview.row like so...

```
dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1 = 'N/A'";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_pr = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_pa = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_tm = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_th = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_obt = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_max = 'N/A       '";
        dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_stat = 'N/A       '";
```

*there are some white spaces in the cell values*

but the output is like below.
[image: Datatable in ReportViewer]

What have i done wrong? is there any other way to hide certain row values based on condition?
all help is deeply appreaciated...

Comment: Why do you add ad then change the filter? Your resulting filter is `dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1_stat = 'N/A       '";`.

Comment: could you explain a bit more as to what is wrong with that code?

Comment: It is better, that you will explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the backslah is causing issue with your filter. You need to escape it somehow

Comment: dv.RowFilter = "Sub_1 = @'N/A'"; try this instead

Comment: invalid element at position 8 exception

Comment: hm..why not remove the whitespace in your data and try again. and also take a look at the data returned